# How to clean up after each Karma test?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, karma-runner

This is my test (Karma + Mocha):

```
describe('foo', function() {
  afterEach(function() {
    var id = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);
    while (id--) {
      window.clearTimeout(id);
    }
  });
  it('works', function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<html/>';
    // add some timeouts here
  });
});
```

The `afterEach` part is exactly the same in all tests. It cleans up the mess after the test. It's obvious code duplication. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a global hook (`before`, `beforeEach`, `after` and `afterEach`) when running each test by defining a method in a setup file.

**test/setup.js**

```
beforeEach(async () => {  
  // your code
})
```

We need to tell Mocha where we can find this file, we can do this by placing the following in the **mocha.opts** (https://mochajs.org/#mochaopts) file.

```
--file ./test/setup.js
```

You can read more about it here: https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks.